How can I use "on error" without making additional loop
I'm preparing macro that copy and paste between sheets and data ranges. Also it's deleting unwanted data.
Workflow is:

Filtering and deleting data from one sheet (if error, then this step should be skipped)
Copy pasting data
Deleting empty rows

Now, if I launch macro for the first time (no data to delete in step 1) then it's working ok.
If there is data in step 1 then macro is going through step 1 - 3 but then it's starting again and duplicating data base on step 2- 3.
I assume that there is issue with "On Error", but I'm not sure how to correctly handle this.
Sub X_MEcopy()
    Dim wbCreatingReports As Workbook
    Dim wsSource1 As Worksheet
    Dim wsBOMInput As Worksheet
    Dim wsBoMMVP As Worksheet
    Dim wsBoM_iPCO_SP As Worksheet
    Dim SAP_PlantValue As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim destFolder As String
    Dim destFile As String
    Dim wsSourceBW_MMR_CY As Worksheet
    Dim wsSourceBW_MMR_PY As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim countME As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Open "Creating reports" workbook
    Set wbCreatingReports = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsBOMInput = wbCreatingReports.Worksheets("BoM Input")
    Set wsBoMMVP = wbCreatingReports.Worksheets("BoM_Spend&MPV PQ")
    Set wsBoM_iPCO_SP = wbCreatingReports.Worksheets("BoM_iPCO&SP PQ")
    filterValue = "ME"

  
   'Step1
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BoM_spend_1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1 _
        :="=ME", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
    lastRow = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    countMEblank = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wsBoMMVP.Range("B3:B" & lastRow))
    countMEvalues = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsBoMMVP.Range("B3:B" & lastRow), "ME")
    countTotal = countMEblank + countMEvalues

    For i = 0 To countTotal - 1
    lastRow = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(lastRow & ":" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next i
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
   
    
    'Step2
        ' Filter the data in the source file based on the filter value (5th column)
        wsBOMInput.AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = wsBOMInput.Cells(wsBOMInput.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRow2 = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lastRow2 = lastRow2 + 1
        lastRow3 = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        
        
        wsBOMInput.Select
        Columns("B:B").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=4
        Range("BoM[[#Headers],[Source]]").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BoM").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=filterValue
        countME = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsBOMInput.Range("B:B"), "ME")
           
  
        Sheets("BoM_Spend&MPV PQ").Select
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=2

    
        ' Copy the visible (filtered) data (excluding header) to the destination file
        With wsBOMInput.Range("A6:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("A" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        With wsBOMInput.Range("C6:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("C" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        With wsBOMInput.Range("D6:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("E" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        With wsBOMInput.Range("G6:Q" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("J" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        With wsBOMInput.Range("R6:S" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("AC" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        With wsBOMInput.Range("T6:T" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        wsBoMMVP.Range("BB" & lastRow2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End With
        
        ' Write the value UNIT to the last row 
        For i = 0 To countME
        wsBoMMVP.Cells(lastRow2 + i, 31).Value = "PC"
        Next i
        
        
        ' Write the value UNIT to the last row 
        For i = 0 To countME
        wsBoMMVP.Cells(lastRow2 + i, 32).Value = "No"
        Next i
        
        ' Write the value UNIT to the last row 
        For i = 0 To countME
        wsBoMMVP.Cells(lastRow2 + i, 33).Value = "No"
        Next i
        
        ' Write the value UNIT to the last row 
        For i = 0 To countME
        wsBoMMVP.Cells(lastRow2 + i, 52).Value = "100%"
        Next i
        
        ' Write the value UNIT to the last row 
        For i = 0 To countME
        wsBoMMVP.Cells(lastRow2 + i, 53).Value = "100%"
        Next i
        
        Sheets("BoM Input").Select
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1
        Sheets("BoM_Spend&MPV PQ").Select
        ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=0, ColumnLevels:=1


    'Step3
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BoM_spend_1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1 _
        :="="
    lastRow = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    countME = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(wsBoMMVP.Range("B3:B" & lastRow))
    

    For i = 0 To countME - 1
    lastRow = wsBoMMVP.Cells(wsBoMMVP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Rows(lastRow & ":" & lastRow).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
    Next i
    
    Sheets("BoM_Spend&MPV PQ").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BoM_spend_1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2

    Sheets("BoM Input").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("BoM").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2



End Sub




Test your assumption - comment out On Error Resume Next, run your code and see what happens.
Or step through it in Debug mode

Already done it as mentioned if I launch macro for the first time (no data to delete in step 1) then it's working ok. If there is data in step 1 then macro is going through step 1 - 3 but then it's starting again and duplicating data base on step 2- 3.
